# Creating a variable filename for every new file in loop,python

Tags: python, file, io

I have been trying to get this code to work for hours. But it just doesn't work, the files are being created. But all that is i'm getting back from the file is stuff which doesn't make sense to me.

```
x=raw_input()
p=open(str(x) + ".txt", 'w+')
p.write("Test#1")
print p.read();
p.close()
```

Some of the ouputs are:

```
w(name, string='') - Return a new hashing object using the named algorithm;
    optionally initialized with a string.
    N(
```

Comment: You should close and reopen the file to flush your input buffer:

Comment: At a minimum calling `read` on a file opened for write only isn't legal, and if it were legal you'd need to do a seek back to the beginning before reading.

Comment: @ToddKnarr - The file was opened with `'w+'` mode, which means for writing and reading. Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing to the file, you need to move (seek) the file pointer to the beginning of the file in order for read to work:

```
x=raw_input()
p=open(str(x) + ".txt", 'w+')
p.write("Test#1")
p.seek(0)  # <== Seek to the beginning
print p.read()
p.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of handling this is to close the file after writing it and re-open it for reading:

```
x=raw_input()
p=open(str(x) + ".txt", 'w+')
p.write("Test#1")
p.close()
p=open(str(x) + ".txt", 'r')
print p.read();
p.close()
```